# Entity Framework Core Scaffold - Dynamic Schema Name

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I'm having an issue at the moment where, we have a database which was already created, so used ef scaffold to create a model of it - the schema the model was created against is called "xxxx-dev".

Now, this has been fine, but in preparation to go live, I created a new DB server and provisioned the database to be called "xxxx-live". Switched the connection string, and attempted a query against it, and got an error.

It seems that scaffolding has hard-coded the schema name into every table in the OnModelCreating call, for example:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<xxxx>(entity =>
{
...
entity.ToTable("xxxx", "xxxx-dev");
...
});
```

This is a bit of an issue as going forward, we might have multi-tenant sites based on the same database, and obviously the query overriding the connection string every query isn't a great experience.

Is there anyway to configure the schema name, either in the Scaffold, or at runtime? I've done a bit of searching around and can't seem to see a solution.

Thanks,

Comment: The scaffolded code isn't cast in stone. Just modify it, that's what it's for. It's easy enough to supply the schema name by some variable/parameter.

Comment: The problem being everytime we re-scaffold due to future development we lose the modifications and have to do it again

Comment: That's improper usage of scaffolding. I see people do it all the time, but the purpose of scaffolding is to give you a one-time only kick start in *code-first (!)* development.